# Grep Result filter double result

Tags: bash, ffprobe

i need to extract only the first Ita audio from grep :

```
ffprobe -i La.casa.nera.1991.FULL.HD.1080p.DTS+AC3.ITAENG.SUB.LFi.mkv 2>&1 | grep "Stream" | grep -v "Video" | grep -v "Subtitle"  | grep  "ac3" | egrep "(Ita)|(ita)|Italian|Italiano|italian|italiano|Eng|eng|English|english"
```

result :

```
Stream #0:2(ita): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s
Stream #0:4(ita): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s
Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s
```

i need to have only the first ita audio like this :

```
Stream #0:2(ita): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s
Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s
```

can help, best regards

Comment: Please do post sample of  input and expected output in your post, this could be done by a single `sed` or `awk` etc. Let us know.

Comment: Side note: egrep has -i so you will not need both Ita|ita (assuming that you don't have to avoid something like iTa)

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what are you asking. For the sample you have, `uniq -s12` would do the trick:

```
ffprobe -i La.casa.nera.1991.FULL.HD.1080p.DTS+AC3.ITAENG.SUB.LFi.mkv 2>&1 | grep "Stream" | grep -v "Video" | grep -v "Subtitle"  | grep  "ac3" | egrep "(Ita)|(ita)|Italian|Italiano|italian|italiano|Eng|eng|English|english" | uniq -s12

Stream #0:2(ita): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s
Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s
```

Explanation:

- `-s` instructs uniq to skip the first 12 chars so uniqnes will be considered only for `(ita): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s`

However, if the 2 Italian streams have different frequency or other properties, a awk command may be necessary:

```
awk  '!a[substr($2,6,length($2)-7)]++'
Stream #0:2(ita): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s
Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s
```

Explanation:

- `$2` selects the second field `#0:2(ita)` for example
- `substr` extracts the `ita` part (since I'm not sure of the command output, I assumed that `ita` may have variable length
- `!a[..]` - print only if the `a` dictionary doesn't have an entry already

Answer (score -1):

Add `| head -1` to your command,

 or add `-m1` flag to your `grep`

From `grep` manual:

```
-m num, --max-count=num # Stop reading the file after num matches.
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need only italian, I would advise this :

```
ffprobe -i La.casa.nera.1991.FULL.HD.1080p.DTS+AC3.ITAENG.SUB.LFi.mkv 2>&1 | grep "Stream" | grep -v "Video" | grep -v "Subtitle"  | grep  "ac3" | egrep "(Ita)|(ita)|Italian|Italiano|italian|italiano" | head -1
```

Remove english and add `| head -1` if you want the first or `| tail -1` if you want the last

Comment: i need only one italian and one english

Answer (score -2):

this is only example have a loop from many mkv file and need to select only one track italian adn one track english. on this situation have 2 audio

this is debug info:

Movie Name : La.casa.nera.1991.FULL.HD.1080p.DTS+AC3.ITAENG.SUB.LFi.mkv
Trovate 3 tracce DTS e 3 tracce AC3 :

Count DTS Tracks :  3
Count AC3 Tracks :  3

```
Stream #0:1(ita): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
Stream #0:2(ita): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s
Stream #0:3(ita): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 1536 kb/s
Stream #0:4(ita): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s
Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 1536 kb/s
Stream #0:6(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 640 kb/s
```

Preferenza sorgente audio selezionata : ac3
Audio ID ITA :  2 4
Audio ID ENG :  6

the problem is Audio ID ITA give me 2 result and the command ffmpeg not work.

```
$FFMPEG_BIN -y \
        -i $MOVIE_INPUT"/"$FILE_NAME \
        -i /home/mich/Eagle-Horror.png \
        -filter_complex "color=s=1920x1080:c=black [base] ; \
        [base][0:v] overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2, drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf: text='%{pts \: hms}': x=20: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=0: boxcolor=0x00000000@1: fontsize=12, drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf: text='$MOVIE_NAME - $FILM_TIME - Disponibile in multilingua': x=25: y=h-(2*lh)-20: fontcolor=white: box=0 [over];\
        [over][1:v] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-40:40" \
        -pix_fmt yuv420p \
        -vsync 1 \
        -threads 0 \
        -map 0:0 -c:v h264_nvenc -profile:v high -preset:v slow -level 4.1 -vb 4500k -maxrate 4700k -bufsize 6000k -r 23.976 -map_metadata -1 -map_chapters -1 -t $FILM_DURATION -metadata:s:v:0 language=ita \
        -map 0:"$AUDIO_ID_ITA" -c:a aac -ab 640k -ac 5 -metadata:s:a:0 language=ita \
        -map 0:"$AUDIO_ID_ENG" -c:a aac -ab 640k -ac 5 -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng \
        $MOVIE_OUTPUT"/"$FILE_NAME-new.mp4
```

Comment: This should not be an answer, it should be added to the question